# Reading data of a mat file in visual c++ by MatIO

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mat-file

I want to read a mat file in visual C++ by matI/o library. I add `#include<matio.h>` to headers and add folder of headers to `VC++ Directories>include dir` . My mat file (opt.mat) has a structure that its field are some matrices. I want to read data of these matrices.
I write these codes,(opt.mat has a field with name "numsample") But when I check 'matvar' in end of debugging this code , this is empty and its field doesn't any thing . Where is problem?

My codes:

```
mat_t    *matfp;
matvar_t *matvar;
matfp = Mat_Open("opt.mat",MAT_ACC_RDONLY);
matvar = Mat_VarReadInfo(matfp,"x");
matvar=Mat_VarGetStructFieldByName(matvar,"numsample",1);
```

Comment: Try putting the file `matio.cpp` or the file that contains the `Mat_Open` function in the same directory as `matio.h`

Comment: hm seems you've posted the same (or very similar/related) question 3 times already? why don't you stick to one and improve that?

Comment: @nyarlathotep on other question I want to try this work by mat.h library of Matlab instead of matI/O library

Comment: @rcs .. thanks alot.. by adding c++ file the problem solved

Answer (score 2):

This is a useful resource: http://sourceforge.net/p/matio/discussion/609376/thread/9df1158c/

The code shown in this exactly explains how to read from and write to a mat file. be sure to read the entire thread.